# Grouping and subtotalling

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, subtotal

I am currently writing a report which I wish to group by the field apar_id and also have a sub total for each of these.
Given my limited knowledged and being bambozled by many google answer I am asking for your kind input.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT d.apar_name,a.*,b.rel_value,c.dim_b
FROM acutrans a 
LEFT JOIN aglrelvalue b ON a.apar_id=b.att_value
LEFT JOIN acrtrees c ON b.rel_value=c.cat_1
LEFT JOIN acuheader d ON a.apar_id=d.apar_id
WHERE b.rel_attr_id='212'
AND b.attribute_id='A4'
AND a.client='CL'
AND a.client=b.client
AND a.client=c.client
AND c.att_agrid='60'
AND (b.rel_value='X24' OR c.dim_b='PCT')
ORDER BY a.apar_id
```

The results are similar to
    apar_id | ..... | amount.....
    x                 100
    x                 300
    x                 -100
    Y                 400
    Y                 100

and would like

```
apar_id | ..... | amount.....
x                 100
x                 300
x                 -100
Total X           300
Y                 400
Y                 100
Total Y           500
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't run subtotals in an SQL statement.  Or at least, you can't do so and also provide the detail level.  The question is, in what software application are you running the query, and what tools does it provide for group and sum?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm glad *you're* the dba and not *me* !

Answer (score 1):

Many databases support the `with rollup` clause for `group by`.  If yours does, you can do what you want by making this a `group by` statement.

```
SELECT d.apar_name, sum(amount) as amount
FROM acutrans a 
LEFT JOIN aglrelvalue b ON a.apar_id=b.att_value
LEFT JOIN acrtrees c ON b.rel_value=c.cat_1
LEFT JOIN acuheader d ON a.apar_id=d.apar_id
WHERE b.rel_attr_id='212'
AND b.attribute_id='A4'
AND a.client='CL'
AND a.client=b.client
AND a.client=c.client
AND c.att_agrid='60'
AND (b.rel_value='X24' OR c.dim_b='PCT')
GROUP BY d.apar_name WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will not specifically solve this problem, although you can adapt this solution (if your database supports it).